# Jasmine and AngularJS - Unit testing a mocked dependency

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have an `AuthService` that has a dependency on `userService` which comes from a different module

I'm trying to write a unit test that checks a property of the `userService` which I have mocked out and included using the $provide service in my test spec.

```
beforeEach(function() {
    module('app.services');
    //Need to provide userService since it lives in a different module
    module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('userService', function(){
            return {
                userLoggedIn: false
            }
        });
    });
});

//Question - will injecting _userService_ pick up the mocked instance from above?
beforeEach(inject(function(_AuthService_, _userService_) {
    authService = _AuthService_;
    userService = _userService_;
}));

describe('some text', function() {
    it('should make a get request to check the users token', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('/auth/checktoken').respond({});
        authService.hasAccessToken();
        $httpBackend.flush();
    });
    it('should set userService.userLoggedIn to be true', function() {
        expect(userService.userLoggedIn).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

My expectation on my userService fails since it comes back as undefined. What do I need to do in order to test my mocked out `userService`?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Ok so based on the comments, I can get it to pass by organising my tests like so

```
  describe('hasAccessToken', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){
      authService.hasAccessToken();
    });
    it('should make a get request to catalogues', function() {
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/auth/checktoken').respond({});
      $httpBackend.flush();
    });
    it('should set userService.userLoggedIn to be true', function() {
      $httpBackend.expectGET('/auth/checktoken').respond({});
      $httpBackend.flush();
      expect(userService.userLoggedIn).toBeTruthy();
    });
  });
```

As you can see I'm trying to write a test for the expectGET and the userService separately, is this correct? Just seems quite verbose??

Comment: Is the act of injecting the authService sufficient to set userLoggedIn to true, or are you missing a call? Something  like authService.login(user);

Comment: Yes sorry I have updated my code snippet, so there's an earlier test that makes a call to `authService.hasAccessToken()` which sets `userService.userLoggedIn` to true

Comment: The beforeEach method runs before each test, and as you know it resets the state of the userService. You could put the call to hasAccessToken into your beforeEach method, or call it in each test as you prefer.

Comment: Hi Mark, yes ok, that makes sense - so I have updated my OP with how I have got this to work, but it feels wrong, perhaps I'm over complicating it?

Comment: The first test ('should make a get request to catalogues') has no expectations, what is it testing?

Comment: Ah ok I'm having a face palm moment now... I thought I could use httpBackend.expectGET in the same way as an expect so it could live as a separate test. But that looks like I have misunderstood it's real usage

Answer (score 0):

You are using the angular's `value` synthetic sugar for provider, but you supply a constructor, which should be used with the `service` syntax.

try to use the service constructor with the `service` syntax instaed:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.service('userService', function(){
        return {
            userLoggedIn: false
        }
    });
});
```

or just use the service's instance with the `value` syntax:

```
beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
    $provide.value('userService', {
            userLoggedIn: false
        }
    });
});
```

see angular docs: [$provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide)